# Woocommerce Show/Hide Variation on the basis of Other Variation Value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a variation, for example size. I also created two other variations like Crush-Fabric, Smooth Fabric.

Size = 2,3

When 2 is selected, then Crush-Fabric show, when 3 is selected Smooth Fabric Show in WooCommerce.

I have tried multiple plugins and codes, nothing is gain. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 products instead of variations.

It works more like this. ◙ Category ◘ product • variations and variations would be the variations of the product. These are independent of each other. You want to do two products.

Comment: Sorry, not understand?

Comment: Please check screen shot https://snipboard.io/e3ZQtr.jpg or please check the website https://www.beduniverse.co.uk/collections/bed-frames/products/chesterfield-sleigh-bed-frame-designer-end-soft-velvet-with-matching-fabric-buttons

Comment: Where you can see Fabric functionality, I would like to do the same, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you please check screen shot https://snipboard.io/VLgyFM.jpg

Comment: Can you please elaborate little bit? so that i can work on it?

Comment: Dallas - could you edit your answer to summarise your comment list, and then delete the comments? It is probably at risk of deletion in the Review Queue at present, as it is very brief.